# Download S3 files which has epoch time as a file name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I am writing Java code to download S3 file from a S3bucket. The file names in the S3 bucket is saved as an epoch time. For example: 1555459288 (Apr 17 2019 00:01:28 UTC/GMT). Every one minute or so, the a file is added to the S3 bucket. As the file saved in epoch time, there is no pattern of the file name (If we convert it to human readable format). My requirement is to download a file from the S3 bucket which was created 10 hours ago. Let's say it is now 04:16:2020:20:00, I want to download the file which was created in 04:16:2020:10:00 (or just before that). I have the S3 bucket name. But I don't know can I create the key to download the Java file as the file name is epoch.

I know the S3BUCKET

```
S3Object fullObject = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(S3BUCKET, key));
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fullObject.getObjectContent(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.length() != 0) {
                    //procees code
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //error handling code 
        }
```

I need help with how to find the key. Can we also find and download the files with modified date. Thanks

Comment: `list_objects_v2` is the API call to list objects in the bucket.

Comment: Since you don't know the filename, your choice is to either list the contents of the bucket and then try to figure out which file you want, or use Amazon S3 Events to trigger an AWS Lambda function when the file is created. The Lambda function could store this information in a database that can later be referenced.